# Issue with Sudo Yum Install Java on Windows terminal

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to install Java 8 using my Windows command line but whenever I write "$ sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk" and hit enter, I get the following error message:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 11:41:34 ago on Sun Mar 26 08:15:24 2023.
No match for argument: java-1.8.0-openjdk
Error: Unable to find a match: java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

I have already created a PATH for Java 1.8 by editing the environment variables but somehow I am not able to install it. Is there an alternative command I should try?

Comment: Isn't Sudo a special system part for Into Linux?

Comment: Facing same error. did you figure it out?